# what does this line do in Perl? ($rowcol =~ m/([A-Z]?)([0-9]+)/);

Tags: regex, perl

What does this line do in Perl?

```
my @parsedarray = ($rowcol =~ m/([A-Z]?)([0-9]+)/);
```

$rowcol is something like A1, D8 etc... and I know that the script somehow splits them up because the next two lines are these:

```
my $row = $parsedarray[0];
my $col = $parsedarray[1];
```

I just can't see what this line does  ($rowcol =~ m/([A-Z]?)([0-9]+)/);  and how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator m// is a pattern match, basically a synonym of //.  This matches an optional first letter and then 1 or more digits in row column.  An array is returned as the result of the match with each element containing one of the matched groups (in brackets).  Therefore $parsedarray[0] contains the letter (or nothing) and $parsedarray[1] contains the digits.

Answer (score 7):

`([A-Z]?)` means capture at most one uppercase letter. `([0-9]+)` means match and capture at least one digit.

Next time, you can install [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAPE::Regex::Explain) to tell you what's going on. eg

```
 use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
 my $regex = "([A-Z]?)([0-9]+)";
 my $exp = YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($regex)->explain;
 print $exp."\n";
```

Note that `m//` in list context returns all the captured sub-strings.

Answer (score 3):

Broken into pieces, this is what's going on:

```
my @parsedarray =                   # declare an array, and assign it the results of:
                  (
                   $rowcol =~       # the results of $rowcol matched against
                              m/    # the pattern:
                                ([A-Z]?)   # 0 or 1 upper-case-alpha characters (1st submatch),
                                           # followed by
                                ([0-9]+)   # 1 or more numeric characters (2nd submatch)
                               /x          # this flag added to allow this verbose formatting
                  );                # ...which in list context is all the submatches
```

So if `$rowcal = 'D3'`:

```
my @parsedarray = ('D3' =~ m/([A-Z]?)([0-9]+)/);  # which reduces to:
my @parsedarray = ('D', '3');
```

You can read about regular expressions in depth at [perldoc perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) (a quick summary), [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (the tutorial), and [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (all the details), and the various regular expression operations (matching, substitution, translation) at [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Answer (score 1):

It:

- matches against the regular expression (zero or more capitalised letters, followed by one or more numbers.)
- Captures two groups:

  - zero or more letters
  - one or more numbers
- Assigns those captured groups to the `@parsedarray` array

Example code to test:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $rowcol = "A1";
my @parsedarray = ($rowcol =~ m/([A-Z]?)([0-9]+)/);
print Dumper(\@parsedarray);
```

yields:

> $VAR1 = [
>             'A',
>             '1'
>           ];

Note that if the string had no leading capitalised letter (e.g. "`a1`") then it would return an empty string for `$parsedarray[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

My Perl is a little rusty but if I understood your question, the answer is that it matches the regular expression of :

optional any capital letter between a through z followed by one or more number digits, and assigns it to rowcol